# Broken PHP install? Unmet dependencies on any package

Tags: php, debian, failed-installation

I need to enable APC on my server, however not a single package will install (even php5 says it has unmet dependencies but is installed already)

The error I am getting says it will not install the packages. I tried `-f` and `--fix-missing` to no avail

```
apt-get -f install php5 php5-fpm php-pear php5-common php5-mcrypt php5-mysql php5-cli php5-gd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5-cli : Depends: libdb5.1 but it is not installable
            Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not installable
            Depends: libxml2 (>= 2.8.0) but 2.7.8.dfsg-2+squeeze8 is to be installed
            Depends: libedit2 (>= 2.11-20080614-4) but 2.11-20080614-2 is to be installed
 php5-common : Depends: psmisc (>= 22.15-1~) but 22.11-1 is to be installed
 php5-fpm : Depends: libdb5.1 but it is not installable
            Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not installable
            Depends: libxml2 (>= 2.8.0) but 2.7.8.dfsg-2+squeeze8 is to be installed
 php5-gd : Depends: libjpeg8 (>= 8c) but it is not going to be installed
 php5-mcrypt : Depends: libltdl7 (>= 2.4.2) but 2.2.6b-2 is to be installed
 php5-mysql : Depends: libmysqlclient18 (>= 5.5.24+dfsg-1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

“It is not installable“ means APT does not know where to get this package. You either have incompatible sources in `/etc/apt` or you need to update the package cache with `apt-get update`.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a bit, but the sources added were to instal php5-fpm and ultimately php apc, not it says these packages aren't available.

Comment: It says php5-fpm is available (likely from the added sources) but it depends on libdb5.1 which is not (probably should be in distribution sources). This usually means you added sources for a different version of your distribution than you have.

Comment: I made a comment to his commit that he mislabeled OS version